# Does convergence in $L^p$ imply convergence in distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

> $f_1,f_2,\dots ,$ and $f$ are in $L_{loc}^1(U)$.
>
> Prove that if
>
> $f_n\in L^p(U)(1\leq p\leq \infty)$ and $f_n\to f$ in the $L^p$ norm or weakly in $L^p$,
>
> then $f_n\to f$ in $\mathcal{D}^\prime (U)$,
>
> where $\mathcal{D}^\prime (U)$ denotes the space of all distributions on $U$.

I'm really stuck and I would appreciate if you indicate what aspect of $L^p$ convergence I should look at to tackle this problem. Any hints or suggestions would help.

Thank you.

Comment: $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $\mathcal{D}'(U)$ if and only if $(f_n,\phi) \rightarrow (f,\phi)$ for every $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(U)$, where $(g,\phi) = \int_U g\phi$. Note that $|(g,\phi)| \leq \|g\|_p \|\phi\|_q$ by Holder's inequality for a conjugate exponent $q$. Use $g = f-f_n$ and bilinearity of $(\cdot,\cdot)$, or simply the definition of weak $L^p$ convergence.

Comment: @snar I was stricken by the same question, and your vision about its solution is profound. It really helps a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a test function $\phi\in D(U)$ and consider the $f_n$ as distributions:

$$\begin{align}|\langle f_n,\phi\rangle-\langle f ,\phi\rangle|&=\left|\int_U\left(f_n(x)-f(x)\right)\phi(x)dx\right|\\
&\le   \int_U |f_n(x)-f(x)|\cdot|\phi(x)|dx\\
&\le \|f_n-f\|_{L^p(U)}\cdot\|\phi\|_{L^q(U)}\end{align}$$
with $\frac 1p+\frac 1q=1$ for Hölder's inequality. Therefore, if $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$, then the above difference converges to zero for any test function and hence we have the convergence in $D'(U)$.

Weak convergence is treated similarly: as $\phi\in L^p$, the integral $$\int_U\left(f_n(x)-f(x)\right)\phi(x)dx$$ converges to zero and hence we also have the convergence in $D'(U)$.

Comment: Thank you, @TZakrevskiy. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

$f_n \to f$ in $D'$ if

$$\forall \phi \in D, \ \lim_n \int_U (f-f_n)\phi\, dx = 0$$

If the convergence is strong in $L^p$, Hölder inequality gives us the result :

$$\left|\int_U (f-f_n)\phi\, dx \right| \leq \int_U \left|(f-f_n)\phi \right|\,dx \leq \|f_n-f\|_p\|\phi\|_q \to 0$$

If the convergence is weak, as $D\subset L_q$, the answer is immediate

Comment: Thank you @Tryss. I couldn't come up with Hoelder inequality. It was really helpful.